# Java - Integration testing GraphQL mutations secured methods with @PreAuthorize roles from Keycloak

Tags: java, spring-security, graphql, integration-testing, keycloak

**What I've got so far:**

- I have working unit tests that return access denied by Spring Security which verifies that my roles are set up correctly with Keycloak.
- I have successfully tested a controller that does not have Spring Security implemented and gives the expected result.
- I have also tried to run the GraphQl mutation via Insomnia with a service account that has no roles get a 403 forbidden
- I have also tried to run the same GraphQl mutation via Insomnia with a service account that has admin role and no role, both mutations carry out successfully. (Screenshots included)

**Goal:**

- I am trying to write an integration test for my Java Spring project that uses `@WithMockUser` to simulate a role from Keycloak.

Method from controller:

```java
  @MutationMapping
  @PreAuthorize("hasRole(admin)")
  public Entity addEntity(@Valid @Argument EntityInput input) {
    var entity =
        Entity.builder()
            .name(input.getName())
            .description(input.getDescription() != null ? input.getDescription() : "")
            .customId(input.getCustomId() != null ? input.getCustomId() : "")
            .notBefore(input.getNotBefore().toInstant())
            .expires(input.getExpires() != null ? input.getExpires().toInstant() : null)
            .entityType(input.getEntityType())
            .archived(false)
            .build();

    return entityRepository.persistAndFlush(entity);
  }
```

my GraphQl Schema for testing

```
mutation AddEntity($input: EntityInput!) {
  addEntityl(input: $input) {
    name
    description
    customId
    entityType
    notBefore
    expires
    archived
  }
}
```

My test

```java
@Autowired private WebGraphQlTester graphQlTester;

@WithMockUser(username = "Test", roles={"read_only"})
@Test
void addEntity_with_readonly_role_return_403_forbidden() {
 var entityInput =
 Map.of(
  "customId",
  "Testing",
  "name",
  "Test name",
  "description",
  "Test description",
  "entityType",
  "MANUAL",
  "notBefore",
  "2023-06-28T13:37:00Z",
  "expires",
  "2023-07-04T13:37:00Z");

  graphQlTester
   .documentName("entities")
   .operationName("AddEntity")
   .variable("input", entityInput)
   .execute()
   .errors()
   .satisfy(
     errors -> {
      assertThat(errors).hasSize(1);
      assertThat(errors.get(0).getErrorType()).isEqualTo(ErrorType.FORBIDDEN);
 });
}
```

Results from Insomnia:

[image: With roles]
[image: With no role]

Edit:

I've also dug a little deeper and found that WebGraphQlTester does not support @WithMockUser as it does not update the security context. If anybody has a workaround or other solution, please post.

Comment: As of the current version: `1.2.0` of Spring GraphQL (March 2023) and listed in their documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#testing.httpgraphqltester WebGraphQLTester only supports basic and/or bearer authentication headers. Thus using `@WithMockUser` does not change the security context.

Current solution is to wait for Spring GraphQL to implement support for this.

If I find any workarounds that work with my stack, I'll report it here.

Answer (score 0):

For testing custom roles (or any advanced security setup) I have resorted to simply inserting a mock/test implementation of `Authentication` into `SecurityContextHolder`. E.g. I'm using JWT so I build the token as follows:

```
private fun buildAuthentication(user: User): JwtAuthenticationToken {
    val unusedAttributes = mapOf("some" to "attribute")
    val unusedHeaders = mapOf("some" to "header")
    val claims = mapOf("sub" to user.subject, "email" to user.email)
    val authorities = listOf(OAuth2UserAuthority("ROLE_CLIENT", unusedAttributes))
    val jwt = Jwt("token", null, null, unusedHeaders, claims)
    return JwtAuthenticationToken(jwt, authorities)
}
```

Instead of `ROLE_CLIENT` you can put there any role(s) your test wants to assume.

You can even create your own annotation resulting in a similar usage to `@WithMockUser`:

```
@WithSecurityContext(factory = TestUserSecurityContextFactory::class)
annotation class WithTestUserSecurityContext


class TestUserSecurityContextFactory : WithSecurityContextFactory<WithTestUserSecurityContext> {
    override fun createSecurityContext(annotation: WithTestUserSecurityContext) =
        SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext().apply { authentication = buildAuthentication(TEST_USER) }
    }
}
```